# Why do multiline strings skip intended whitespace at the beginning?

Tags: rust, string-literals

I have some multiline strings with intended whitespace. For some of those, some whitespace is removed:

```rust
const WORKING: &str = "\
┌─┬┐
│ ││
╞═╪╡
│ ││
├─┼┤
├─┼┤
│ ││
└─┴┘
";

const NON_WORKING: &str = "\
  ╷ 
  │ 
╶─┼╴
  │ 
╶─┼╴
╶─┼╴
  │ 
  ╵ 
";

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", WORKING);
    println!("{}", NON_WORKING);
}
```

It removes some whitespace at the beginning of the line in the non-working one. Printing:

```
╷ 
  │ 
╶─┼╴
  │ 
╶─┼╴
╶─┼╴
  │ 
  ╵
```

I think it has to deal with the use of `\` but **I don't know how to solve it without starting the line after the `"`**

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c18cd59d7743e4ece12336d31fcbf33e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard [the `indoc` crate](https://crates.io/crates/indoc) is intended to help write multiline string literals containing indentation. It removes leading whitespace equally from all lines, rather than `\`'s behavior of removing leading whitespace from each line independently.

> #### Using indoc
>
> ```rust
> use indoc::indoc;
>
> fn main() {
>     let testing = indoc! {"
>         def hello():
>             print('Hello, world!')
>
>         hello()
>     "};
>     let expected = "def hello():\n    print('Hello, world!')\n\nhello()\n";
>     assert_eq!(testing, expected);
> }
> ```

Comment: Actually this didnt work exaclty as I would expect for some of the strings I had. I'm adding a new answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rust will automatically remove intended whitespace, as long strings are usually broken into multiple lines like this, with the whitespace being just for formatting purposes.

You can use [raw strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals) to disable this behavior. Notice the extra `r` and the custom delimiter `#` at the start and end.

```
const NON_WORKING: &str = r#"
  ╷ 
  │ 
╶─┼╴
  │ 
╶─┼╴
╶─┼╴
  │ 
  ╵ 
"#;
```

Comment: I tried this, but this have an extra line at the beginning iirc.

Comment: This is the newline after `r#"`. If you don't want it, use `const NON_WORKING: &str = "  ╷ ` as your first line

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the purpose. Keep the alignment and the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used plain str and removed the initial `\n`:

```rust
let WORKING: &str ="
 ── 
    
 ── 
    
 ── 
 ── 
    
 ── ".trim_start_matches("\n")
```